# How to change root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB library to turn a Java object into an XML file.
Now the output that I get is:

```
<company>
     <name>Amazon</name>
</company>
```

What I want to get is:

```
<companies>
      <company>
         <name>Amazon</name>
    </company>
</companies>
```

How can I reach my goal? Do I have to remove `@XmlRootElement` from the Java object (and of curse doing something else)?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Company {  
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Or should I edit the class the uses the `Marshaller` methods?

```
public String marshall(BasicModel basicModel){      
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(basicModel.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();       
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);     

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(basicModel, writer);             

            return writer.toString();   
    }
```

Comment: How does your POJOs look like? Do you have a simple list of companies to serialize? A list of company names? Or simple a single company name that you want to wrap in XML?
Ideally, you don't have to change your POJO to adapt to the XML format you want. JAXB provides you with the right tools.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a wrapper class and serialize it, it will work no matter if `Company` also is a `@XmlRootElement`  :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "companies")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Companies {  

    @XmlElement(name = "company")
    List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

    // getters , setters...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Test {
    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Companies {
        private Company[] company;

        public Companies(){}
        public Companies(Company[] company){this.company = company;}

        public Company[] getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public void setCompany(Company[] company) {
            this.company = company;
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Company {  
        private String name;

        public Company(){}
        public Company(String name){this.name = name;}

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static String marshall(Object basicModel) throws JAXBException{      
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(basicModel.getClass());
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();       
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);     

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(basicModel, writer);             

        return writer.toString();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Company comp1 = new Company("test");
        System.out.println(marshall(comp1));
        Companies c = new Companies();
        Company[] compArr = new Company[1];
        compArr[0] = comp1;
        c.setCompany(compArr);
        System.out.println(marshall(c));
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<company>
    <name>test</name>
</company>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<companies>
    <company>
        <name>test</name>
    </company>
</companies>
```

(I used an array becase I am assuming that you would like to persist a list of companies.)

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final String data = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element element = element("companies").child(simple.fromXml(data));
System.out.println(simple.domToXml(element));
```

Will output;

```
<companies><company><name>Amazon</name></company></companies>
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```